# Problema con action redux, devuelve objeto anidados

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

estoy aprendiendo redux haciendo una página de crear notas, esta haciendo click en ella puedes cambiar la importancia de la nota, no se por que pero al crear 1 nota cambia perfectamente pero al crear otra nota y tener 2 o mas notas creadas en la lista, cuando le haces click te devuelvo un objeto, en el que dentro de ese objeto tienes otro objecto con los datos y no encuentro el fallo, dejo lo que aparece en el state al darle click cuando hay mas de 1 nota creada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver, la nota con 1 se dividio en 2 y eso hace que los datos de la nota desaparezcan en la lista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dejo mi codigo lo mas abreviado
index.js

```
   const store = createStore(
 noteReducer,
 window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

const Store = () => {
 const state = store.getState();

 const addNote = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const { target } = e;
   const content = target.note.value;
   target.note.value = '';
   store.dispatch(createNote(content));
 };

 const toggleImportant = (id) => {
   store.dispatch(actionToggleImportant(id));
 };

 return (
   <>
     <form onSubmit={addNote}>
       <input name="note" />
       <button>add</button>
     </form>
     <ul>
       <li>Aqui empieza la lista</li>
       {state.map(note => {
         return <li key={note.id} onClick={() => toggleImportant(note.id)}>
             {note.content}
            <strong>
               {note.important ? "is important" : "not important"}
             </strong>
           </li>
       })}
     </ul>
   </>
 );
```

};

y este es mi reducer

```
export const noteReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "@notes/created":
      console.log("nota creada");
      return [...state, action.payload];
      break;

    case "@notes/toggle_important":
      console.log("cambiando importancia");
      const { id } = action.payload;
      return state.map((note) => {
        if (note.id == id) {
          return {
            ...note,
            important: !note.important,
          };
        }else {
          return state;
        }
        
      });

    default:
      return state;
      break;
  }
};

export const generateID = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999) + 1;
};

export const createNote = (content) => {
  return {
    type: "@notes/created",
    payload: {
      content: content,
      important: false,
      id: generateID(),
    },
  };
};

export const actionToggleImportant = (id) => {
  return {
    type: "@notes/toggle_important",
    payload: {
      id: id
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Ok entonces cada vez que das click en add the aparece este objeto el cual parece ser un array de objetos que contiene las notas, ¿Puedes confirmar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EL problem esta en que estas retornando el state dentro del map cuando el id no es el mismo. El código tuyo es este

```
 return state.map((note) => {
        if (note.id == id) {
          return {
            ...note,
            important: !note.important,
          };
        }else {
          return state;
        }
        
      });
```

Cuando debería de ser

```
 return state.map((note) => {
        if (note.id == id) {
          return {
            ...note,
            important: !note.important,
          };
        } else {
          return note;
        }
        
      });
```

El return del else es la diferencia

Comment: Muchas gracias, vaya error mas tontin